# Capturing video with AVFoundation stops right after starting, only produces single image instead of video

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avcapturesession

The code below is supposed to capture a video, but it only captures a single image. It was pulled together by looking at other SO posts and the Apple docs.

What happens is the "video" stops recording immediately after starting, producing a single image -- even though in the code it's not supposed to stop until a button is tapped.

The class docs don't seem to suggest there is a "mode" property that needs to get flipped to take video instead of images, so what is missing?

```
private func initCamera() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    for device in devices {
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    beginSession()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


func beginSession() {
    do {
        try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
    } catch {
        print("Error creating AVCaptureDeviceInput: \(error)")
    }

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer!.frame = cameraView.layer.frame
    cameraView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, atIndex: 0)
    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
    captureSession.startRunning()
}


@IBAction func captureButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    if (videoFileOutput.recording) {
        videoFileOutput.stopRecording()
        return
    }

    // If here, start recording
    let tempFilename = getUniqueFilename(".mov", numChars: 15)
    let tempPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingFormat("/\(tempFilename)") as String
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: tempPath)
    videoFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(fileURL, recordingDelegate: self)
}


func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    print("Finished recording @ \(outputFileURL)")

    // Create player & layer
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: outputFileURL)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer!.frame = playerView.frame
    playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer!, atIndex: 0)
}


func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
    print("Started recording")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key was catching the error in `captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!)`, which revealed there was a disk space issue.